# What is wrong in plotting this function?

Tags: plotting, functions

I plot this function $\frac{\coth (x)-5 \coth (5 x)}{7 x}-2 x^3$

```
Plot[(  Coth[x] - 5 Coth[5 x])/(7 x) - 2 x^3, {x, 0, 0.8}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {-1.5, -1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}]
```

and I obtain

[image]

Here I see a vertical line on the $f(x)$ axis. Then, when I diminish the domain of $x$ as $0<x<0.0000001$ and plot it

```
Plot[(  Coth[x] - 5 Coth[5 x])/(7 x) - 2 x^3, {x, 0, 0.0000001}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {-1.5, -1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}]
```

it gives this plot

[image]

Is this result correct? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Add the option `WorkingPrecision -> 30` to `Plot`.

Comment: @JimB Thank you very much. Doing so gives the same result as the first picture. But for example, if I calculate the value of the function for  $x=0.0000000001$, it gives $2724.78$, but according to the first plot, it must be negative.

Comment: Compare `f[0.0000000001]` (machine precision) with `f[0.0000000001\`30]` (arbitrary precision) or `f[SetPrecision[0.0000000001, 30]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you so much. It works.

Comment: The value as `x` approaches zero is `Limit[(Coth[x] - 5 Coth[5 x])/(7 x) - 2 x^3, x -> 0]` which evaluates to `-8/7`